# File Uploading issue on cpanel

Tags: php, laravel, file, cpanel

I have deployed a laravel website on cPanel. I have a zip file of 19.1mb when ever i try to upload this file through form in my website  got an error

> There were some problems with your input.
> The file_uploads.0 failed to upload.

I do not understand why this is happening. I have checked my cPanel setting of max file size upload it is 8M. I have updated max_execution_time to 5 minutes but nothing changed.
Please let me know if you have any solution for this
Thank you

Comment: Did you increase max file size upload?

Comment: yes the max upload memory limit on my hosting is 8M